# Link to nomenclature not reaching the correct page

Tags: hyperref, nomenclature

I have attached the [pdf output](https://leeds365-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/sccd_leeds_ac_uk/EcokN2tb47JLnIcrLP0xBe4B6ZrsXN7fcZg9TLpNEgoQ4w?e=XFUmRS) of essentially what the problem is. In the document I have a nomenclature at the end. The nomenclature contains definitions with hyperlinks to the 1st time the entry appears in the document. These links work well and clicking on them sends me to the correct place.

Each definition appears in the main text in two ways. The first time it appears it will be in magenta text and links to the nomenclature (likewise this is where the nomenclature links to). Each time after the text will be black but will still be clickable and send the reader to the nomenclature (where they would then be able to click the link to find where it is first defined for more details than what they nomenclature gives.

The links from the nomenclature work perfectly in sending the reader to the 1st time the item is defined. However, neither of the links in the main text correctly link to the nomenclature (in the pdf document if you click on one you end up at chapter 7).

Basically the magenta text (and black text links) that have been defined by the user commands should be linking to the nomenclature but it fails and I cant figure out why!

I believe the key things are

```
\usepackage[intoc, refpage]{nomencl}
    \renewcommand{\nomname}{Notation index}
    \renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\unskip, page \hyperpage{#1}}
    \makenomenclature
```

and then how I define the link to the nomenclature

```
\printnomenclature{}\hypertarget{abbr}
```

or

```
\hypertarget{abbr}{\printnomenclature{}}
```

Neither of which work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=2cm, inner=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}     % makes table of contents
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}   
\usepackage{tocbibind}              % ads toc to toc
\usepackage{subfigure}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% HYPERLINKS
\usepackage[hidelinks, pageanchor]{hyperref}    % Load after fancyhdr, float, fncychap; before algorithm, cleveref
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=red}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}     % Must load after hyperref
    \crefformat{section}{\S#2#1#3}  % See manual of cleveref, section 8.2.1

% GNOMES
\usepackage[intoc, refpage]{nomencl}
    \renewcommand{\nomname}{Notation index}
    \renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\unskip, page \hyperpage{#1}}
    \makenomenclature

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%this is for gnomes
\newcommand{\gnome}[1]             {    \hyperlink{abbr}{ \textcolor{black}{ #1}}   }
\newcommand{\gnomedef}[3] {     \hyperlink{abbr}{\textcolor{magenta}{#1}}\nomenclature{#2}{#3}   }


\begin{document}
    
    
\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter 1}
\gnomedef{something}{something}{something} 

\gnome{something} 

\chapter{chapter 2}
\chapter{chapter 3}
\chapter{chapter 4}
\chapter{chapter 5}
\chapter{chapter 6}
\chapter{chapter 7}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1.2em}
\hypertarget{abbr}{\printnomenclature{}}

%\printnomenclature{}\hypertarget{abbr}
\cleardoublepage
    

\end{document}
```

EDIT -  Solution found.
For the table of contents problem

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage\protect\cleardoublepage}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\textbf{Contents}}
}

\fancypagestyle{style1}{ 
    \pagestyle{fancyplain}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}          % 0pt no header rule; 0.4pt standard header rule
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage      \hypertarget{toc}}
    \fancyhead[LO]{}
    \fancyhead[RE]{}
    \cfoot{}
}
```

works.

For the nomenclature links problem the solution seems to be to not use nomenclature but to use the glossaries package.

Comment: (1) welcome to the size, (2) please make this example both minimal (you are loading a lot of irrelevant stuff) and self contained, we don't have those chapters. Thus please make a document that is minimal, self contained and show the problem you have. Then it is easier for others to copy your example, see if they also have issue and then help.

Comment: Updated it to remove as much as possible. Not sure I can remove anymore than this.

Comment: What do you mean "have youyr chapters?" The chapters are simply empty placeholders to demonstrate a link in text not ending up at the nomenclature page. I am not sure what you mean by \include. There are no instances of \include in the above code.

Comment: My bad, it read it wrong, long day

Comment: Instead do you mind a bit more explicitly explaining what it actually is you want to do. It is not at all obvious what the end goal is

Comment: Sure. One of the problems is not major so I will edit the post and make it explicitly for the major problem! (I think the minor problem is related so tried to combine them... probably a mistake!)